# WSO2 Enterprise Store add fields to mobileapp

Tags: wso2, wso2-es

how can I add a new custom field to mobileapp asset into WSO2 Enterpise Store ?
For example an app can have price or category and to be possible to make query by this fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Side Note**
Which version of the ES are you using?

**Answer**

The process for doing this changes depending on whether you have already started the ES once.

In the case where the ES has been run atleast once:

1. Login to the admin console
2. Click on the extensions tab
3. Select Artifact Types
4. Select the mobileapp artifact type from the list of artifacts
5. See **Editing RXT section** below

If you have **not** started the ES atleast **once** then:

1. Navigate to the {CARBON_HOME}/repository/resources/rxts folder
2. Open the mobileapp.rxt with a text editor such as gedit (linux) or notepad (windows)
3. See **Editing RXT section** below

**Editing an RXT**

- Extra fields can be added by including field elements
- An explanation of how to configure a RXT , URL:https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Governance+Artifacts+Configuration+Model+Elements

Comment: I'm running EMM 1.1.0, and on carbon tab Extensions I don't have menu Artifact Types. I need to add anything else ?

Comment: Fixed, install the latest features and then ... found